# Delphi How to exit to TOP level routine on Error

Tags: delphi, exception, control-flow

In Delphi,  I have a hierarchy of routines.  Routine 'A' calls 'B' which calls 'C' which calls 'D'.  'D' does some checking, and it encounters an error of some type, maybe an Exception,maybe just a logical error.  Regardless, when 'D' encounters the error, is there anyway for control to pass back to 'A' without having 'D' return a 'failure' code, which 'C' checks for, which returns a failure code, which 'B' checks for, etc...?

Comment: If you raise an exception in D and have a try-except block in A, you can catch it there. you could raise a T_D_Exception so you can recognize it in A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are exactly two ways to do what you want:

1. Return an error/status code and have every function on the call stack check that code.
2. Raise an exception and handle it at the high level.

You do not wish to use option 1, so that leaves option 2.

Comment: Take note that you have now chosen for an 'error propagation method' that you have to stick to: don't ever introduce another try/except in B or C, unless it re-raises the exception. If your system gets larger it's very easy to forget that ;-)